# Powershell Export-Excel : not displaying any data

Tags: excel, powershell, shell

I am working on a script to export a basic xlsx file with few data to a xlsx file with a table (so I can grab it into power apps since power apps  only allow datasource who are in table format).

I have installed the powershell module import-Excel who seems to do exactly what I want.

First I import the data from a xlsx workbook :

```
$xlfile = "C:\Users\xxx\WebScrappor\Scrappor.xlsx"
Import-excel  $xlfile -WorksheetName Sheet1 -NoHeader -ImportColumns @(6, 7, 9, 11)
```

Here is the output I have in the powershell console :

| P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gare sol | 2400 | 6400 | 37.50 |
| gare icpe | 4500 | 65000 | 27,50 |

So clearly the data are being imported correctly. I am then trying to export them to another excel in the excel table format (that gives you the zebra striping and drop down arrows, which enables interactive data filtering.)

```
Select -First 25 | Export-Excel C:\Users\xxx\WebScrappor\Bridge.xlsx -TableName Sheet1 -AutoSize
```

This dos not give me any result, the table is correctly created but there is no data in it :

[image]

I have Tried to import the file with multiple formats.

Comment: Did you forget to pipe that select line after the first line?